# Making each line a variable in Bash,

Tags: bash

I have a command that does a docker inspect, and creates a variable containing a list of containers and any associated IP addresses. The container name is listed on the same line as its interface(s) IP(s):

```
sudo docker ps -q | xargs -n 1 sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .Name }} {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}} {{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' | sed 's#^/##'
```

The output is:

```
hostname1  1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
hostname2  3.3.3.3 
hostname3  4.4.4.4 5.5.5.5 6.6.6.6
```

As you can see, some nodes have one interface, some two and some three. The first IP address = eth0, the second = eth1 and the third = eth3.

I want to make each line a new variable, for example:

```
$var1 = hostname1  1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

and then from there, pull out each IP address and run a DNS query against it.

Any ideas how I can achieve making each line a separate variable? and then how to do a for each loop for each of the IPs within this variable?

Comment: Read up on bash arrays and the `readarray` built-in.

Comment: @Shawn : `readarray` is not needed here, `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a` is enough

Comment: assuming the number of input lines is going to vary, you definitely want to give some thought to using an array; whether you use `read`, `readarray`, `mapfile`, or a `while/read` loop will be based on a mix of preference and how you plan to use the data; also depending on your follow-on requirements , you'll need to decide on a 'normal' (integer-indexed) array or an associative array

Comment: Do you actually need to retain all the data for all the hosts at the same time?  having a separate variable for each line suggests so, but your description of the use of the data does not seem to exhibit such a need.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make each line a new variable, for example:
>
> ```
> $var1 = hostname1  1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
> ```

No, you probably don't.  That is, if you don't have a fixed upper bound on how many containers may be reported, or if you don't want to write long, highly repetitive code, then you don't.

And if all you want to do with these data is

> and then from there, pull out each IP address and run a DNS query against it.

then there is no advantage in creating separate variables, or in retaining the data for any given container any longer than it takes to launch the corresponding query.

Nevertheless, if you are determined to read all the output from `docker inspect` before doing anything with any of it then you should read each line into a separate array element, not an altogether separate variable.  This is the function of the `readarray` (a.k.a. `mapfile`) command:

```
declare -a inspect_lines
readarray -t inspect_lines < <( ... docker command ... )
```

Each line will then be accessible as an element of the array: `${inspect_lines[0]}`, `${inspect_lines[1]}`, ....  The total number of lines will be available as `${#inspect_lines[*]}`.

That's not a separate variable per line *per se*, but it's a reasonable facsimile.